# Google Storage ArgumentException when setting CORS config

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cors, google-cloud-storage, bucket, gsutil

Following Google docs, when using *GoogleCloud Storage* console:

```
mysef@myproject:~$ cat cors-json-file.json 
[ 
  {
    "origin": ["*"],
    "method": ["GET"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  } 
]
```

then I get the following error:

```
myself@myproject:~$ gsutil cors set cors-json-file.json gs://mybucket
Setting CORS on gs://mybucket/...
ArgumentException: JSON CORS data could not be loaded from: [ 
  {
    "origin": ["*"],
    "method": ["GET"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  } 
]
```

same error when I remove "method", "maxAgeSeconds" or add "responseHeader".

Comment: gsutil version == 4.19

Answer (score 21, accepted):

after so many tries, I ended up with modifing json file to:

```
$ cat cors-json-file.json 
[{
    "origin": ["*"],
    "method": ["GET"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
}]
```

and... it worked! 
Note that example from Google documentation is my first case (with [{ on 2 lines)

Comment: Thanks this helped me... I had the exact same issue... still dont understand why this works though

Comment: Note: I ran the gsutil command in the question after doing this

Comment: The line breaks as is formatted in this answer work.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and it was caused by the type of quotes used. By opening the json-file in a plain text editor and change the quote to standard ones fixed the problem.

Comment: What do you call "standard ones" ? JSON quotes are double, by definition.

Comment: @comte, by "standard" I mean the regular U+0022 (QUOTATION MARK). Some text editors or CMS might replace the standard quotation mark with U+201C and U+201D (LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK and RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK). If the file content has been copied from somewhere, this might be hard to spot.

Comment: I see what you mean now. But that was not the case for me (and Tyler seems). It wasn't quotation marks the problem.

Comment: Thanks. This solution works for me. Previously I tried to edit the JSON in the online editor, it probably corrupted from there.
After I replace all the double quotes inside vscode, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when I tried to set **the CORS settings** with **the trailing comma ","** as shown below:

```json
[
    {
      "origin": ["http://localhost:8000"],
      "method": ["GET"],
      "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600, 
    }                   // ↑ Trailing comma
]
```

So, I removed **the trailing comma ","** as shown below then I could set **the CORS settings** successfully without no error:

```json
[
    {
      "origin": ["http://localhost:8000"],
      "method": ["GET"],
      "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600 
    }                   // ↑ No trailing comma
]
```